# Passing data from asp.net MVC controller to the View via Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

Hello guys I have got some trouble with ajax that I try to understand what is going on. Well I have got this controller which is returning list of Guider Model, well here is my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult ShowGuiders(string latitude, string longitude)
        {
            double lat = DataTypeConvert.ConvertToDouble(latitude);
            double lon = DataTypeConvert.ConvertToDouble(longitude);
            GeoCoordinate geoCoordinateFrom = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);

            var nearbyGuiders = (from guider in db.Guiders.AsEnumerable()
                                 let distance = geoCoordinateFrom.GetDistanceTo(new GeoCoordinate(guider.Latitude.Value, guider.Longitude.Value))
                                 where distance <= 100000
                                 orderby distance ascending
                                 select guider).ToList();
            return Json(nearbyGuiders, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGet").click(function () {
                var coordinate = {
                    "Latitude": $("#latitude").val(),
                    "Longitude": $("#longitude").val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("ShowGuiders", "Guider")',
                    data: { latitude: coordinate.Latitude, longitude: coordinate.Longitude },
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        // Result
                        alert("Succes");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        //do your own thing
                        alert("fail");
                    }
                });
            }); //end .submit()
        });
    </script>
```

Finally here is my Guider Model:

```
public class Guider
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public string GuiderID { get; set; }
        //code...
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }
        public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CancellationPolicy")]
        public int? CancellationPolicyID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Premium")]
        public int? PremiumID { get; set; }

        public virtual Premium Premium { get; set; }
        public virtual CancellationPolicy CancellationPolicy { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UnavailableDate> UnavailableDates { get; set; }

    }
```

Well the problem was that whenever I was trying to return List of Guider nothing was happening and event of error function of ajax was raising. So I tried to return just an Object of Guider and evrything was working perfectly.
This controller is working perfetcly:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult ShowGuiders(string latitude, string longitude)
        {

            myGuider.Country = "Greece";
            return Json(myGuider, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

So I figured out that Json does not suport my object hierarchy. So I solved my problem with anononymus objects. I modified the controller like this, and I return propperties that I need :

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult ShowGuiders(string latitude, string longitude)
        {
            double lat = DataTypeConvert.ConvertToDouble(latitude);
            double lon = DataTypeConvert.ConvertToDouble(longitude);
            GeoCoordinate geoCoordinateFrom = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);

            var nearbyGuiders = (from guider in db.Guiders.AsEnumerable()
                                 let distance = geoCoordinateFrom.GetDistanceTo(new GeoCoordinate(guider.Latitude.Value, guider.Longitude.Value))
                                 where distance <= 100000
                                 orderby distance ascending
                                 select new { country = guider.Country } ).ToList();
            return Json(nearbyGuiders, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: Please post the code snippets, not screenshots.  Also, please provide the specific error you are receiving in the response.  Are you able to step through the controller action?  How about the javascript?

Comment: Remove the `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` (your not stringifying the data - i.e. using `data: JSON.stringify({ ... }),` so you need to use the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`). And if you sending values which are typeof `double`, then make your parameters `double latitude, double longitude` and let the `DefaultModelBinder` do its work instead of converting them yourself

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes your right but so I will modify it and I will still use strings for latitude and longitude becouse If I wrote inside of textbox the latitude = 40.664547177624414 works good but if I mistakenly write latitude = 40,664547177624414 (with comma) then there is a problem. So I prefer to keep them strings and modify them manually.

Comment: Then that would be an invalid value based on the culture of your server so the correct approach is to catch the error on the client (and the server) and displaying an error message (and consider what happens if the user enters `40.66Lat` - your code would probably just throw an exception). Always validate your data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btnGet").click(function () 
{
    var coordinate = {
        "Latitude": $("#latitude").val(),
        "Longitude": $("#longitude").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: '@Url.Action("ShowGuiders", "Guider")',
             data: { 
                      latitude: coordinate.Latitude, 
                      longitude:coordinate.Longitude 
             },
             success: function (result) {
                        // Result
                        alert("Succes");
             },
             error: function (response) {
                        //do your own thing
                        alert("fail");
             }
   });
```